# Eclipse - Extract/package the required libraries into the same Runnable JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export, executable-jar

When exporting a project as a Runnable JAR file using Eclipse, there are three choices:

```
1. Extract required libraries into generated JAR
2. Package required libraries into generated JAR
3. Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR
```

However, it seems that only one of the three choices could be chosen from the Runnable JAR File Export window. I wonder if there are some ways that could mix up these methods, e.g., extracting some of the files while packaging the rest?

Note: I need this since one of my JAR file contains a ton of references to other files so 1 cannot be an option, and I am afraid that 2 might be causing some problems for me.

Thanks!

Comment: useful explanations of these options at http://auralbits.blogspot.com/2010/10/automating-java-application-packaging.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is choose "1. Extract required libraries into generated JAR" and save the build as an Ant script.  Then after it finishes, edit the ant script and remove the libraries that you do not want to be extracted.