# Problems when using robocode with JESS

Tags: eclipse, freeze, jess, robocode

I'm attempting to use JESS in order to utilise a rule-based system for making a robot. I've got both robocode and the JESS .jar imported into Eclipse. Here's my code -

```
public class myRobot extends Robot {
    Rete r = new Rete();

    public void run() {
        try {
            String reset = "(reset)"; 
            r.executeCommand(reset); 
            String enemyInfo = "(deftemplate enemyInfo (slot present) (slot energy) (slot name))";
            r.executeCommand(enemyInfo);

            while (true) {
                String command = "(assert (enemyInfo (present no) (energy -1) (name none)))";
                r.executeCommand(command);
            }

        } catch (JessException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public void onScannedRobot(ScannedRobotEvent e) {
        try {
            String command = "(assert (enemyInfo (present yes) (energy " + e.getEnergy() + ") (name " + e.getName() + ")))";
            r.executeCommand(command); 
        } catch (JessException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't added in any rules yet because I just wanted to check that robocode and JESS run properly together. When I fire this up, the robocode application opens up. But when I try adding this robot in a battle and starting it, the application just freezes up completely.

I can't access the robot's console to see what's wrong since it hangs just immediately after I try and start a battle. Since all my System.out.println() debugging statements are printed  to the robot's console as opposed to the main one, I can't even figure out what's wrong. Any suggestions to get this to work?

Comment: As far as I can see, you have an infinite loop in myRobot.run(), starting at "while( true )"

Comment: @lauune: this is correct. robocode robots are coded that way. so there's nothing wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the robocode application does not know the JESS library. You will need to include it in the jar of your exported robot.

[How to include librarys to jars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7986589/2316112)