# External library not found when creating runnable jar

Tags: java

I have Java class named `RemoteBluetoothServer` with a main, using the `bluecove-2.1.0` external library.
I'm trying to create a runnable jar.
Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7986589/1869297) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3796824/1869297) posts, I created this ant script:

```
<jar jarfile="${client_deploy_dir}/RemoteBluetoothServer.jar"
     basedir="${client_work_dir}/compiled">
   <manifest>
      <attribute name="Main-Class" value="RemoteBluetoothServer.Main"/>
      <attribute name="Class-Path" value="bluecove-2.1.0.jar"/>
   </manifest>
</jar>
```

I also added `manifest.mf` file to the src folder:

```
Manifest-version: 1.0
Main-Class: RemoteBluetoothServer
Class-path: bluecove-2.1.0.jar
```

After creating the runnable jar using Eclipse Export, the jar file is created, and also `MyProject_lib` directory with the `bluecove-2.1.0` jar file.
 When I run the jar file, I get the error `BlueCove libraries not available`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is bluecove-2.1.0.jar file located under MyProject_lib folder? If so, class-path should be MyProject_lib/bluecove-2.1.0.jar

Comment: @jdiver it didn't helped