# NoClassDefFoundError when running exported JAR from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I've looked up how to export .jars in eclipse online for hours. I've tried all the tutorials and have not been able to open my game. I've used the command prompt with

```
java -jar <name>
```

and get an error that says

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/lwjgl/LWJGLException.

Here's how I export my .jar in eclipse:

1. right click on the project and click on "export..."
2. select "jar"
3. select src, lib and resource folders
4. select .classpath and .project
5. select only "Export generated class files and resources"
6. select destination
7. click next twice
8. select "Generate manifest file"
9. select the main class
10. click finish

Comment: Have you exported it as a **runnable jar**?

Comment: Is the `lwjgl.jar` in your classpath or the class `org/lwjgl/LWJGLException` in your jar file?

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't work @Daniel

Comment: If it's runnable try `java.exe -jar <name>.jar`. Last jar may be optional but it won't hurt.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils No. The error is that a required class file is not found. It has nothing to do with how the JAR is executed.

Comment: I think this problem is because of not adding lwjgl.jar in your classpath.

Comment: lwjgl.jar is already in my classpath.

Comment: @user2981826 Does your application run when you execute it inside Eclipse? If you open the JAR file with Z-zip (or similar), can you find the LWJGLException class file?

Comment: @user2981826 Is the class `org/lwjgl/LWJGLException` in your jar?

Comment: Can you share with us your manifest and your project skeleton? The command **java -jar yourJar.jar** is not right, you have to suggest the path of your classpath

Comment: @Jens org/lwjgl/LWJGLException is inside the lwjgl.jar which is inside of my jar, or does it have to be in the root folder or something?

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: reactionGame.Main

Comment: Maybe you need to pack any external libraries in your Jar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986063/generating-a-jar-in-eclipse-including-external-library

Answer (score 0):

Exporting it as jar will just package your project as an archive only.
If you want to run it from the jar choose

```
Export>Runnable Jar File
```

Make sure you select your main class in the **Launch Configuration**.